# Cartesian (non parametric) form of Bezier curves

Tags: javascript, drawing, bezier

I needed to find and use the coordinates of the intersection of a cubic Bezier and a straight line. The trouble is that I cannot find a non-parametric representation of a Bezier curve which I need for solving with the line.

I do not want to resort to a Newton-Raphson equivalent on the Bezier parametric equation (which can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer for this SO question might help you out:

[Approximating nonparametric cubic Bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427796/approximating-nonparametric-cubic-bezier)